# Some clients take the hour from DC that is not PDC

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-domain

We have two DCs, DC1 and DC2, DC1 have all roles. I configured a GPO for clients to sync with DC1:

[image]

I notice that some domain clients have as time source DC2.

Somebody knows Why ?

DC2 have this option enable, can be the cause ?

[image]

Thanks !

Comment: By default, domain computers will use the authenticating domain controller as time sync server. Domain controllers sync against the PDC.

Answer (score 0):

Some facts:

- Desktops and member servers sync with any domain controller.
- Domain controllers sync with PDC emulator (one per domain)

More from
[How the Windows Time Service Works](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/how-the-windows-time-service-works):

> As part of the time convergence process, domain members attempt to synchronize time with any domain controller located in the same domain. If the computer is a domain controller, it attempts to synchronize with a more authoritative domain controller.

This means that DC2 synchronizes with DC1, but domain members will sync
with any of them.

If you wish DC1 to be the sole NTP server in the domain, you should
disable the NtpServer role of DC2.

Comment: Ok thansk. You mean disable the "Enable" registry key on DC2 ?

Comment: I mean disable the role in the server manager.

Comment: can you tell me how? i dont see the option in server manager.

Comment: It seems like it's done in the Services applet, by disabling the service Windows Time.